# How to redirect firebase to my cloud function for serving SEO capable pages

Tags: firebase

I have a firebase hosting with cloud function. I want to have SEO support for my angularjs App. 
My best solution so far is having function that serves meta tags for bots  and redirect bot requests to my function.

I want to have a redirect to cloud function on bot request for example when user agent is Facebo